# Remove characters between 2 specifics strings in a JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to remove all the characters between the characters `<p` and `</p>` (basically all the attributes in the `p` tags).
With the following block of code, it removes everything, including the text inside the `<p>`

```
MyString.replace(/<p.*>/, '<p>');
```

Example: `<p style="test" class="test">my content</p>` gives `<p></p>`

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What is your expected output after removing ?

Comment: my expected output is <p>my content</p>

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You've clarified it in the comments - edit the question: Add your desired outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this RegEx: `/<p [^>]*>/`, basically just remove the closing bracket from the accepted characters. `.` matches all characters, that's why this doesn't work. With the new one it stops at the first `>`.

Edit: You can add a global and multi-line flag: `/<p [^>]*>/gm`. Also as one of the comments pointed out, removing the tag makes it applicant for every tag, however this will make replacing a bit harder. This RegEx is: `/<[^>]*>/gm`

Comment: Thank you very much ! it works. however i just noticed it updates only the first "p" tag in case of multiple "p" tags in my string ? Do you know how we could extend that to the string in its entirety ?

Comment: @Arn.adg : simply append global flag - `/<p [^>]*>/g`

Comment: @Arn.adg add a global tag and make it multi-line: `/<p [^>]*>/gm`. And as Pramod Mali pointed out, if you remove the `p`, it works for every tag

Comment: replace(/[^>]*>/,"")

Answer (score 0):

```
MyString.replace(/\<p.*<\/p>/, '<p></p>');
```